# createEmptyMovieClip creates it on all frames (AS2)?

Tags: flash, youtube, actionscript-2

I have a question regarding createEmptyMovieClip in AS2. I have a flash file separated out into sections with labels and menu buttons which allow you to move you to the relevant frame/section (which contains the information/contents relevant to that section). This works fine. What I can't work out is that if I manually put a movieclip on the stage in my 'about section' and then add contents to it via AS2 then it only exists within the about us section. If I do it using createEmptyMovieClip within the actions for the about frame this works fine but it then always exists on every other frame of the project. I assume this is because it isn't actually creating it within this frame but I can't work out how to make it do this, even when i use this.createEmptyMovieClip it has exactly the same effect. I can obviously remove the movieclip completely each time a user moves to another frame that doesn't contain it but I don't want to do this as it contains a youtube video and leaving it means it doesn't have to be reloaded each time they come back.

I would be massively grateful if anyone could shed any light on this for me as I know i'm not getting how to place it correctly but i'm not sure how I should be doing it?

Thanks so much in advance,

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the movieclip once, then set `mc._visible = false;` and stop the video when you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, that makes complete sense. For anyone elses' info that is reading this you can also manually create an empty movieclip on the stage and then programmatically add the new mc within this, which will mean it only has the scope of the containing mc.